# Conversion of java object to Date or DateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, inner-join, nativequery

I have a query of inner join tables:

`List<Object[]> resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(SOME QUERY).getResultList();`

When i try to access the elements of `Object[]` one of which is a `Date` I tried doing this:

```
for(Object[] obj : resultList) {
    Date createdDate = obj[7] !=null ? new Date(Long.valueOf(obj[7] + "")) : null;
}
```

This gave obvious exception:

> `nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012-11-20"`

I changed the `Date` to `DateTime` get `TO_CHAR(createdDate,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')`

And tried the below code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date createdDate = null;
try {
    createdDate = df.parse(obj[7] + "");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This approach results: `createdDate = null`

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to parse dates cominf from a SQL query. They should come back as Date or Timestamp instances. Show us your query.

Comment: `select project.project_id, project.business_id, project_status_type.project_status_desc, project.create_dtm,
project.update_dtm, from project_status_type
INNER JOIN project on project_status_type.project_status_type_id = project.project_status_type_id and project.project_id = 12345;`

Comment: What is the DB column type that you store date? Is it DateTime or is it VARCHAR ? If it is DateTime as @JBNizet mentioned you just need to cast your object into a java.sql.Date. If it is VARCHAR and you know the forme (e.g. 2012-11-20) then the below code snippet may be useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You shouldn't have to parse dates coming from a SQL query. They should come back as Date or Timestamp instances. Show us your query.

You prabably have `java.sql.Date` instances coming back, but you're transforming them to Strings by concatenating them with an empty string:

```
obj[7] + ""
```

Just do

```
Date createdDate = (Date) obj[7];
```

Comment: yeah , sorry  just realized it.. deleted the comment +1 :)

Comment: @JB Nizet ya that works, i was not sure didnt try that, thanks :)